# How do I remove date formatting substring in python?

Tags: python, date, pandas, substring

I'm trying to clean up some data and want to check if there is date formatting in a string.  If there is date formatting, I would like to remove it.

For example, I have inputs like this: 
"Midnight 10-22-13 HD"

I also, I want to remove HD and check if there is a date at the end and remove it among other parsing like striping characters after a colon.

```
def func(value):
    str(value)
    if ":" in value:
        return value.split(":", 1)[0]
    if value.endswith('HD'):
        return value[:-3]
    else:
         return value
```

I do not want to assume that the string is last, but rather if it is in the 6 digit - delimenited format and then return the value with out the date.

I'm applying these fucntions to values in a dataframe series

```
 data["LongTitleAdjusted"] = data["Long Title"].apply(func)
```

Here are some examples of inputs:

```
Stand-Up: "Weird Al" Yankovic   
Stand-Up: "Weird Al" Yankovic HD    
Doug Benson 3 HD    
Midnight 11-14-13   
Midnight 11-14-13 HD    
Midnight 01-06-14   
Midnight 01-06-14 HD    
Midnight 01-07-14
```

Desired outputs:

```
Stand-Up
Stand-Up
Doug Benson 3
Midnight 
Midnight 
Midnight 
Midnight 
Midnight
```

Comment: Can you show us an example for the case that has `:` in it? Also, `str(value)` does absolutely nothing, i think you mean `value = str(value)`

Comment: I'm trying to find it a variety of different patterns and then remove them.  Yes, I would like to look for date in entire string and then return the string WITHOUT the date in it.

Comment: @KateLehman Should "Midnight 10-22-13 HD" return "Midnight" or "Midnight HD"? (the regex solution by piRSquared returns "Midnight HD" at the moment). There are lots of things one would have to consider to make a robust solution (are all values space delimited? Can the date be the first element in the string? etc. etc.). It would be easier if you posted more examples of input data (positives and negatives) and the desired output.

Comment: It should return Midnight -- How can I have the run all of the parsing consecutively on the same string?

Comment: @KateLehman Cool cool. I took the liberty of editing the question slightly to make it clearer. Hope you don't mind. From the examples you posted, I think we can derive a few rules. If a colon is found in the string, return everything before the colon, if no colon is found, look for date strings. If no date string is found, return everything before " HD". If a date string is found, return everything before the first space. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lines = [
'Stand-Up: "Weird Al" Yankovic',   
'Stand-Up: "Weird Al" Yankovic HD',    
'Doug Benson 3 HD',    
'Midnight 11-14-13',   
'Midnight 11-14-13 HD',    
'Midnight 01-06-14',   
'Midnight 01-06-14 HD',    
'Midnight 01-07-14'  
]

def clean_string(string):
    clean = string
    if ":" in string:
        clean = string.split(":")[0]
    else:
        if string.endswith(" HD"):
            string = string.replace(" HD", "")
        clean = string.split(" ")
        try:
            datetime.strptime(clean[-1], '%m-%d-%y')
            clean = string.replace(clean[-1], "")
        except ValueError:
            clean = string
    return clean
```

It actually tries to convert the date string to a date; meaning it won't strip out invalid dates (after all, they could be values). If you don't care about this, you can replace it with a regex that finds all numbers, `str`'s `isdigit()` method or something similar.

Output:

```
>>> for line in lines:
...     print clean_string(line)
... 
Stand-Up
Stand-Up
Doug Benson 3
Midnight
Midnight
Midnight
Midnight
Midnight
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Use regex to match date patter and replace it.

```
import re

def func(x):
    return re.sub(r'(.*)\d{2}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}(.*)', r'\1\2', x)
```

Comment: I'm getting NameError: global name 're' is not defined

Comment: I tried:

def func(value):
    str(value)
    return re.sub(r'(.*)\d{2}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}(.*)', r'\1\2', x)
    if ":" in value:
        return value.split(":", 1)[0]
    if value.endswith('HD'):
        return value[:-3]
    else:
        return value

and still got the same name error

Comment: No sorry have never used rejex before!  This is genius thank you @piRSquared